# Can I use the old WebView in Android 4.4 kitkat

Tags: android, webview, chromium, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm having issues with the new chromium WebView and my html.  I would like to know if I can force Android 4.4 devices to load the older (pre Chromium) webView in my android app?

I know the correct way to do this is to update my html to use the latest web standards and make it work with chromium.  But thats not my question.  Do to limited amount time that is not a option.

I have followed the migration tips for Android 4.4
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

I have set targetSdkVersion lower then 18 and still have issues.  As explained in the android link above "there may be other behavioral differences".  And I'm seeing them.  I will post those in a different question.  This question is related to loading the old web view.

Note: I have also looked into using other web engines but those add 20 to 30 megs to my app and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: i don't think it is possible, as I don't see why the older webview would still be present if not used at all, but anyway I would be curious to know the issues you have ran into (as I will soon have to validate a webview app on kitkat as well)

Comment: @njzk2: I would also like to use old WebView on 4.4. The one and only (killer) condition is "Text reflow" function. They simply removed it. For my app it is crucial. I know they are some workarounds, but it is far away from prefect. The most terrible thing is, that on 4.4 is used chromium also for legacy app. No text reflow. That's why I'm affraid of android... some day your app stop working. They should leave the WebView as it is, and add a new component (e.g. ChromiumView) ! (or simply not remove old functions)